# Factorion numbers in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab

In your prob1(), call your separateThreeDigits function to find all factorion numbers between 1 and 999. You may use the built-in function factorial to calculate the factorials of natural numbers. Print the factorion numbers that you find in the standard output.
When I try to run my code, it outputs every integer between 1 and 999, even though I thought it would only print the factorions. I have no idea where I am going wrong, except that I know it is somewhere in prob1().

```
function [hundreds, tens, units] = seperateThreeDigits(x)
if (x<1 ||x>999)
    fprintf('Error! Please enter an integer between 1 and 999 and try again');
    hundreds = [];
    tens = [];
    units = [];
else
    units = mod(x, 10);
    tens = mod(floor(x/10), 10);
    hundreds = mod(floor(x/100), 10);
    fprintf('h=%d, t=%d, u=%d.\n', hundreds, tens, units);
end
end
function prob1()
factorion = [];
factorions = [];
for x = 1:999
    [hundreds, tens, units] = separateThreeDigits(x);
    if x < 10
        factorion = factorial(units);
        if factorion ==x
            factorions = [factorions, x];
        end
    elseif x < 100
        factorion = factorial(tens) + factorial(units);
        if factorion ==x
            factorions = [factorions, x];
        end
    else 
        factorion = factorial(hundreds) + factorial(tens) + factorial(units);
        if factorion ==x
            factorions = [factorions, x];
        end
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You funtions work fine, just a typo in your function name. It should be sep**a**rate instead of sep**e**rate in `function [hundreds, tens, units] = seperateThreeDigits(x)`

Comment out `fprintf('h=%d, t=%d, u=%d.\n', hundreds, tens, units);` in `seperateThreeDigits` and add `factorions` before the last `end` to only print the factorions:

```
...
        if factorion ==x
            factorions = [factorions, x];
        end
    end
end
factorions
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely was not helping having the incorrect spelling.   But, I am still having issues with only printing the factorions.  When I run it, it prints every integer between 1 and 999, instead of just the factorions.